# Best ASP.NET MVC way to generate documents

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a proof of concept web app project.

The idea is : ASP.NET MVC User Interface and ASP.NET MVC Web API linked to a C# class library for access data from an ODBC source and doing business treatments.

In this project, one of the biggest part is generate documents with datas collected on the ODBC, stock them in a file server and send them by mail.

What is the best way to do that? Directly PDF? or first Word (because documents are pretty complex, with charts,...)

The main fact, is that it must be fluent for the end user. May be using asynchronous programming on the server side?

Thanks for your advice and replies :)

Comment: There is no "best" way. You need to choose a document type based on the clients wants/needs.

Comment: Yep, this is the hidden sence of the question... is it better to create word doc and then save as PDF, or build the PDF directly...? Is there any library powerfull enough to build PDF with advanced charts...?

Comment: I'm using SelectPDF but take a look at Open XML and see if that might work for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.charts?view=openxml-2.8.1

Comment: Thanks Sir :), I'll check that